# What is C equivalent of python's map()

Tags: python, c, dictionary

Here is the situation:

Input consist of space-delimited integers/float/doubles type of data.The datatype is going to be the same. The length for the input is decided during runtime. The input appears as follows (single test case per line)

```
1 5 7 9
2 32 5 5 6
2 5 7 43 73 364
1 2
```

In python using the map function, returns a list of the input with the required data type. I need to implement the same using C. Here's what I have tried so far:

1. Use `fgets` and parse the input, but too many chances of failure and/or slow
2. Use functions like `strtol()`, `strok()` etc, but they only work when the size of the input is known.

Any suggestions on how to go about it?

PS: The maximum number of inputs is known, the number of inputs is always below this arbitrarily large value, but their number can vary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question contains *a lot* of talk about things that have nothing to do with `map()`. You should try to avoid this, and be more focused. If there are several things you wonder about, separate them out into their own questions, don't just rant away about the entire problem.

In C there's no way of writing a general "apply this function" code, without first inventing a way to describe all the data involved, then it might be possible.

If you data is integer, you need something like this:

```
int * map_int(const int *input, size_t input_len, int (*func)(int x));
```

The above should return a dynamically allocated array of the same size as the input, where each element is the result of running `func()` on the corresponding input element. That's probably as close to a generic `map()` as you need to come, here.

This could be trivially implemented, like so:

```
int * map_int(const int *input, size_t input_len, int (*func)(int x))
{
  int *out = malloc(input_len * sizeof *out);
  if(out != NULL)
  {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < input_len; ++i)
      out[i] = func(input[i]); 
  }
  return out;
}
```

Note that the above will assume `func` to be valid; a more reasonable general-purpose function should probably treat a `NULL` function pointer as the identity map. Also note that it does heap-allocation and moves ownership to the caller. A more reasonable implementation should perhaps support caller-owned buffers, too.